# gedit underscore as a word_character

Tags: configuration, syntax, gedit

Is it possible to configure gedit to treat the underscore character as a word character?

Currently, it appears that the editor treats "two_words" as two separate words when selecting, instead of a single word as in many other mainstream text editors.

Comment: Intriguingly, this is now a standard feature and I'm trying to work out how to disable it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be an open requested feature (some may say bug!).

However, it looks like someone has created a plugin to resolve:

http://code.google.com/p/gedit-click-config/

Comment: If anything, this is a wish, not a bug.

Comment: a missing essential feature, let's say ;)

Comment: I can't get this plugin to work in gedit 3.10. Use https://github.com/rubencaro/gedit_click_regex instead. (Listed here https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/ThirdPartyPlugins-v3.8)

Comment: @Zantier How do I install above mentioned plugin?

Comment: @Sangram I don't remember. Googling "gedit install plugin" should help you.